# Does not give the relative domain path after application release C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a class library and windows forms library. In my class library, i have used, for an example, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"ffmpeg.exe"` to access ffmpeg in the current path as a process. But after releasing the executable files, FFmpeg.exe doesn't run. I have tried `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` and 
`( new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
).AbsolutePath;` and more options. Nothing worked

Comment: Surely you would need a \ in there as well? What about `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"ffmpeg.exe")`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
ProcessModule module = process.MainModule;

string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(module.FileName);
string ffmpeg_path = Path.Combine(dir,"ffmpeg.exe");
```

Comment: It didn't work actually..thank you...is there a way to do this in app.config file?

Comment: Define didn't work? Assuming `ffmpreg.exe` is in the same directory as your exe it should have worked fine. Most likely where your ffmpeg is relative to your application is wrong.

Comment: It means the applicaiton doesn't take ffmpeg.exe as a process. It is in the same directory. It actually works in the same computer in different locations. But when in another pc, it doesn't.